# Что из приведенного будет в .bss секции данных?

Tags: c++

Что в данном примере будет храниться в секции неинициализированных данных (bss)?

```
int a;
int arr[20];

int main(){}
```

Попробую высказать свои предложения: `а` будет инициализирована нулём, ибо имеет статическую продолжительность хранения и попадет в `data` сегмент. Но что насчёт массива, где будет лежать он?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/***Нудные оговорки:***/ 
 Строго говоря, С++ ничего не говорит про секции данных — это понятия уровня конкретной платформы и линкера, так что: **а)** вопрос не имеет смысла в отрыве от платформы **б)** компилятор волен сделать всё как считает нужнsv.

---

Все переменные со статическим сроком хранения (и `tread_local`) не снабжённые явной константной инициализацией (*constant-initialized*) инициализируются изначально нулями (*zero-initialized*). При этом для составных типов (структуры/классы, объединения или массивы) данных каждый их член также инициализируется нулём (для объединений немного по-другому это сформулировано, но сути это не меняет).

Обычно компиляторы помещают все нулевые объекты в секцию `.bss`. При этом не важно вызвано это явной инициализацией нулём или нет. Так что в примере выше, скорей всего, оба объекта (`a` и `arr`) будут находится в секции .bss. Это не сложно проверить:

```
alexander@goblin /tmp $ cat foo.cpp
int a;
int arr[20];

int main(){}
alexander@goblin /tmp $ gcc foo.cpp
alexander@goblin /tmp $ objdump -t a.out

a.out:     формат файла elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
# ...
0000000000004060 g     O .bss   0000000000000004              a
0000000000004028 g       .bss   0000000000000000              __bss_start
0000000000001125 g     F .text  000000000000000b              main
0000000000004080 g     O .bss   0000000000000050              arr
# ...
```

Comment: Если формулировать некоторое правило, то все что не инициализированно лежит в bss, кроме локальных переменных, правильно? И действует ли это для static переменных?

Comment: Я если честно запутался:( Если переменные со статической продолжительностью хранения инициализируются нулем(хоть и неявно), то почему они попадают в bss?

Comment: @n1kzzz, когда программа стартует, еще до вызова main, вся область .bss обнуляется как единое целое. Поэтому инициализация всех статических переменных нулем получается автоматически

Comment: @n1kzzz, обобщая в bss оказываются все объекты **со статическим временем хранения** (грубо говоря, это глобальные переменные и статические переменные и переменные-члены), которые не инициализируются **константой** (кроме неинициализированных это также включает те, что инициализируются конструктором или не-constexpr-выражением). В bss они помещаются чтобы не тратить на них место в исполняемом файле и время на их загрузку в память: во время загрузки программы этот сегмент обнуляется средствами ОС.